# My android studio is installing two apps/apks on my phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Ok here is the thing I created a project put it on github, then work more on it update it and push updates on github (this is the last version, 2 versions total)...however now whenever I run the app through android studio,(even the version downloaded from github, master) it installs two APPs on my phone...one is the older version and the other is the new version.. How can I remove the old version ? however I only see one android manifest, it seems that both versions are kinda connected together whenever I uninstall, the phone uninstalls them both

EDIT Before fixing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".TeacherLogin">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddUpdateStudent" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewAllStudents" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NoteMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AddNotesActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

After Fixing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".TeacherLogin">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddUpdateStudent" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewAllStudents" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".NoteMainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".AddNotesActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity">

    </activity>
</application>
```

Ok so appearntly the second intent was after the main menu which was the version 1.0 before the update, after the update I added login activity, hence why it looked like "2 apps with different versions" so there was no problem what so ever with git or github as I weirdly thought... I appologize if this question was kinda stupid now after I looked at it but I am really new to this android app development.

Comment: Please read [ask]. You haven't given us enough information to answer.

Comment: Most likely, you do not have two apps -- you have two `<activity>` elements in your manifest each with the `<intent-filter>` to cause it to appear in the launcher.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks ! looked it up and it was true ! deleted the extra <intent-filter> and problem is gone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two launcher icons, but only one entry in Settings > Apps, that means your one app has a manifest with two `<activity>` elements that each have the `<intent-filter>` to cause them to appear in the launcher:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".SomeOtherActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

That may just be a copy/paste error, or perhaps an accidental checkbox click in the new-activity wizard.

Regardless, unless you really *do* want two launcher icons, remove the `<intent-filter>` from the activity that does not belong in the launcher.